# How does Love Potion know for whom the victim should fall?

Tags: harry-potter

Polyjuice Potion recognizes the victim (whose identity is compromised) by using his/her hair or something.

In case of Love Potion, victims actually eat or drink the Love Potion, but how does Love Potion know who the attacker (with whom the victim get infatuated) is?

When Love Potion is brewed, it certainly is neutral without attacker identity. That's why, so many of girls were able to order the Love Potion from *Weasleys' Wizard Wheezes*. What do girls do to the Love Potion after getting it and before sending it to target boy?

Comment: I always assumed that there was a hair/DNA element as well,  just like Polyjuice Potion.

Comment: @Adamant But, it isn't listed as ingredient.

Comment: @ChristieRomanowski - Where is this list of ingredients that you refer to?

Comment: Magic seems to be capable of understanding ownership, e.g., the [Mokeskin Pouch](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Mokeskin_pouch).  So it might be as simple as "it makes you fall in love with the owner of the potion".

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any evidence in the books, but when watching the movie I always got the impression that the victim develops an enchanted infatuation for the first person they see after — or perhaps the most recent person they have seen before — taking the potion.

In the package Romilda Vane used to attempt to seduce Harry, there was a card with her own picture in it. Ron ate a chocolate laced with love potion, looked at the card, and fell in love with Romilda.

[image: Romilda's]

Comment: Add a quote and your answer will go from good to great.

Comment: Now, that's a new theory. Can you back it up with canon quotes?

Comment: the love potions listed at http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Love_Potion all have the description "Causes the drinker to become infatuated with the giver of the potion". But they don't address how that works. I think there are different kinds, some working like you explained (with the first person you see), others might work with a piece of dna (like polyjuice potions) and maybe other kinds might exist as well

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb here and just say...."magic"